# WebFlux: How to abort request processing in WebFilter with provided response

Tags: spring-webflux

I'd like to do something like below in my WebFilter to optionally bypass subsequent filters and RestControllers:

```
if(shouldRedirect(exchange)){
  //do redirect
}else if(!canAccess(exchange)){
  //return a 403 response
}else{
  chain.filter(exchange);
}
```

How am I supposed to do that?

Thanks

Leon

Answer (score 14):

Technically, the contract says that the filter has to return `Mono<Void>`, which completes when the exchange (request+response) has been processed.

The usual `WebFilter` does something on the request/response and then forwards the exchange to the next filter in the chain. But you can also unilaterally process the exchange and call it done.

In this sample, we're setting the status code and calling the response done.

```
class MyFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        return response.setComplete();
    }

}
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks a  lot!

Comment: 1 more question about setComplete(), is it force response body to flush? If I have some filter before this filter which will add some http header to response, will it fail due to response already committed?

Comment: if you've got filters earlier in the chain, they're fine modifying headers as long as they're doing that before calling the next filter in the chain. Otherwise chances are the response might be already committed - by another filter, or a controller.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Brian's answer...

If you want to write some bytes in your response, you can:

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT);
    return exchange.getResponse().writeWith( Mono.just(exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory().wrap("233".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
}
```

In case you have some model to write to your response, you can:

```
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    Pet pet = new Pet("type", "petFromFilter");
    return ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(pet))
        .flatMap(serverResponse -> serverResponse.writeTo(exchange, new Context() {
             @NonNull
             @Override
             public List<HttpMessageWriter<?>> messageWriters() {
                 // serverCodecConfigurer is an autowired field.
                 return serverCodecConfigurer.getWriters();
             }

             @NonNull
             @Override
             public List<ViewResolver> viewResolvers() {
                 return Collections.emptyList();
             }
}));
```